# Function to remove number between brackets and their signs outside them on python?

Tags: python

I am trying:

```
s="+(1)*F_1 + (0)*F_2 - (1)*F_3"
import re
s_filter  = ' '.join((re.findall(r"\((\d)\)",s)))
print(s_filter)
```

however I am only getting:

```
1 1 1
```

how can I also get the sign outside the brack for the F_3 as well? thanks a lot!

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: What do you mean by *sign outside the brack for the F_3*

Answer (score 0):

You can search for one of `[+-]` then optionally whitespace, then digits enclosed in parentheses.

```
>>> re.findall(r'[+-] *\(\d+\)', s)
['+(1)', '+ (0)', '- (1)']
```

You can also add capture groups if you want to pick apart the sign and the digit for later processing

```
>>> re.findall(r'([+-]) *\((\d+)\)', s)
[('+', '1'), ('+', '0'), ('-', '1')]
```

and it looks like you are trying to join into a single string at the end, so you can process those in a generator expression

```
>>> ' '.join(i+j for i,j in re.findall(r'([+-]) *\((\d+)\)', s))
'+1 +0 -1'
```

Comment: amazing! really appreciated. Is there any way I could save each value and sign in a single excel sheet cell separately?